# Android EditText scrolled into view on Keyboard open without fitsSystemWindow=true

Tags: android

I have a ViewPager which houses a few full screen (No action bar) images. The last view in this pager is a form which when scrolled to DOES have the action bar (Set to overlay on the screen).

I desire to have the edit texts scroll into view when the keyboard is triggered.

I have set windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" on the activity.

If I set fitsSystemWindows=true on the activity's style, the images leave room for the Action bar which isn't there. But the form will scroll correctly.

If I set fitsSystemWindows=false on the activity style then clicking on an input doesn't scroll to be visible when the keyboard is triggered.

If I set fitsSystemWindows=true on the Form, then the form appears under the Action bar and you cannot scroll down until the keyboard is triggered. Then you can scroll the form all the way.

I have tried to do something like this:

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, view.getBottom());
    }
});
```

run when the Edit text is in focus paired with fitsSystemWindows=false, but since the resizing isn't functioning, some edit texts don't scroll in view because there isn't enough space below them.

I have also tried to invalidate the right view when the form is shown so that the new fitsSystemWindows value may take effect. But that didn't work. I tried

```
viewPager.invalidate();
// AND
viewPager.getParent().invalidate();
// AND
getWindow().getDecorView().invalidate();
```

I think perhaps the best solution would be to invalidate the correct view to have the option take effect but I am unsure which view to invalidate. Any ideas? Is there possibly something I need to change in my architecture of my page to get this working?  Or is this maybe not really that possible?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who may encounter this problem in the future what ended up doing was:
make everything `fitsSystemWindows=true` which fixes the forms resize issue. I then in my `activity.onCreate()` added a margin to the top of the Slider Images which is equal to the actionbar height gotten from the system by getting the style associated with `android.R.attr.actionBarStyle` and got the value for `android.R.attr.height` from that style. This should always be the height of the actionbar.